# Make Java Swing Modal Dialog Behave Like Mac OSX Dialogs

Tags: java, macos, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

I am writing a small app that requires a ProgressBar to appear centred under the frame's TitleBar as is often seen in Mac OSX apps. I have two problems:

**1**. I have managed the positioning but I had to hard code the parent Frame's TitleBar height. Is there a 'soft' way to get the TitleBar's height?

In the Dialog's constructor:

```
 Dimension dimensionParentFrame = parent.getSize();
 Dimension dimensionDialog = getSize();
 int x = parent.getX() + ((dimensionParentFrame.width - dimensionDialog.width)/2);
 setLocation(x, parent.getY() + 22);              // TODO HARD CODE WARNING TITLE HEIGHT
```

**2**. Even though the Dialog is modal, I can still click on the parent Frame and move it. How can I make the Dialog 'stick' to the parent Frame? That is, when the parent Frame is moved the Dialog moves with it as if attached.

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


    public class ModalDialogDemoFrame extends JFrame
    {
      ModalDialogDemoFrame modalDialogDemo;
      public ModalDialogDemoFrame() 
      {
        modalDialogDemo = this;
        setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton buttonDialog = new JButton("Open Dialog");
        buttonDialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
          {
            // Create a Modal Dialog with this Frame as Parent.
            ModalDialog modalDialog = new ModalDialog(modalDialogDemo, true);
            modalDialog.setVisible(true);
          }
        });
        getContentPane().add(buttonDialog, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      }

      /**
       * @param args
       */
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            try
            {
              ModalDialogDemoFrame window = new ModalDialogDemoFrame();
              window.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        });
      }

    }

    import java.awt.Dimension;

    import javax.swing.JDialog;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


    public class ModalDialog extends JDialog
    {
      public ModalDialog(JFrame parent, boolean modal) 
      {
        super(parent, modal);
        Dimension dimensionParentFrame = parent.getSize();
        setSize(new Dimension((parent == null) ? 300 : dimensionParentFrame.width / 2, 75));
        Dimension dimensionDialog = getSize();
        int x = parent.getX() + ((dimensionParentFrame.width - dimensionDialog.width)/2);
        setLocation(x, parent.getY() + parent.getInsets().top);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setModal(modal);
        setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton buttonClose = new JButton("Close");
        buttonClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
          {
            dispose();
          }
        });
        getContentPane().add(buttonClose, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      }

    }
```

Comment: *"Even though the Dialog is modal, I can still click on the parent Frame"*  Is the frame the parent of the dialog?

Comment: Yes Andrew, the frame IS the parent of the Dialog.

Answer (score 3):

```
int titleBarHeight = frame.getInsets().top;
```

> Even though the Dialog is modal, I can still click on the parent Frame and move it.

Then you are doing something wrong because this should NOT happen.

Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: frame.getInsets().top; is correct, it gets the TitleBar height. Thanks.

Comment: Here is SSCCE with two classes, a parent JFrame and a JDialog. Run, click on 'Open Dialog' button to load Dialog. Then click on JFrame's TitleBar and move it.

Comment: Please note that I am running this on an iMac on OSX 10.6, I don't know if this makes a difference.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that a modal JDialog on OSX does NOT stop it's owner JFrame from being moved. True, you cannot do anything with the owner JFrame but it just does not feel right.

Comment: I see that Quaqua has done what I require but it took a lot of code using a ComponentAdapter to achieve the desired results...