# What to do about dialog box being displayed outside of eclipse program

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

First I'm new to Java and am taking a beginner's course. Is the use of the % symbol in some cases not allowed in eclipse? in my code when I used the printf method if I use only one percent symbol it gives me an error however when I use 2 it works just fine. It runs the way it should but another issue I'm having is this code prints both to the console and in a dialog box and for some reason the dialog box doesn't get displayed in eclipse if i minimize eclipse i see it show up on my desktop. When i try it in Jgrasp this doesn't happen. Any ideas why this happens?

```
public class Project6
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
  {    
    double diamondCost;     // Cost of diamond
    double settingCost;     // Cost of setting diamond
    int numOrdered;         // Number of diamonds ordered
    double baseCost;        // settingCost + diamondCost
    double totalCost;      // Total cost of diamond including labor and tax
    double laborCost;      // Cost of jewler's labor
    double stateTax;       // State tax  
    double luxuryTax;      // Luxury tax
    double finalAmountDue;  // totalCost*numOrdered
    double stateRate=0.10;   
    double luxuryRate=0.20;  
    double laborRate=0.05;    

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the cost of the diamond");
    diamondCost = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the cost of setting the diamond");
    settingCost = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of diamonds you want to order");
    numOrdered = keyboard.nextInt();

    baseCost = diamondCost + settingCost;
    luxuryTax = calcExtraCost(baseCost, luxuryRate);
    stateTax = calcExtraCost(baseCost, stateRate);
    laborCost = calcExtraCost(baseCost, laborRate);
    totalCost = baseCost+luxuryTax+stateTax+laborCost;
    finalAmountDue = calcExtraCost(totalCost, numOrdered);

    System.out.println("Jasmine Jewelry:TOTAL COST BREAKDOWN");
    System.out.printf("Diamond Cost: ----- $%.2f\n", diamondCost);
    System.out.printf("Setting Cost: ----- $%.2f\n", settingCost);
    System.out.printf("State Tax @ 10%%: ----- $%.2f\n", stateTax);
    System.out.printf("Luxury Tax @ 20%%: ----- $%.2f\n", luxuryTax);
    System.out.printf("Labor Cost @ 5%%: ----- $%.2f\n", laborCost);
    System.out.printf("Total Price each: ----- $%.2f\n", totalCost);
    System.out.println("Number ordered: " + numOrdered);
    System.out.printf("Final Amount Due: $%.2f", finalAmountDue);

    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jasmine Jewelry: TOTAL COST BREAKDOWN\n" + "Diamond Cost: ----- $" + 
    formatter.format(diamondCost) + "\n" +"Setting Cost: ----- $" +    formatter.format(settingCost) +  "\n" +
    "State Tax @ 10%: ----- $" + formatter.format(stateTax) + "\n" + "Luxury Tax @ 20%: ----- $" +
    formatter.format(luxuryTax) + "\n" + "Labor Cost @ 5%: ----- $" + formatter.format(laborCost) + "\n" + 
    "Total cost each: ----- $" + formatter.format(totalCost) + "\n\n" +"Number ordered: " + numOrdered 
    + "\n\nTotal Amount Due: $" + formatter.format(finalAmountDue));

    keyboard.close(); // To close scanner object
    System.exit(0);

  } // End main method

 static double calcExtraCost(double diamond, double rate) 
 {
    double extraCharge = diamond*rate;
    return extraCharge;

  } // End method calcExtraCost
} // End class Project6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all printf uses % to mark positions which will be filled with variables later on
f.ex. your

```
System.out.printf("Diamond Cost: ----- $%.2f\n", diamondCost);
```

will insert the variable diamondCost at the position of the % character. If you want to print a % character you need to use %%.

Second the problem with your MessageDialog seems to be related that the MessageDialog has no parent.

Maybe [how to show JOptionPane on the top of all windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880981/how-to-show-joptionpane-on-the-top-of-all-windows) is related to that.