# Show JOptionPane (with dropdown menu) on the top of other windows

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, window, joptionpane

I am working on a program that shows the following `menu` ([menu_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsPOb.png)) when it starts. I have a little problem: I'd want to show it on the top of the other windows, but I am not able to achieve this.

```
class Menu {
    public String showMenu(){
        Object[] options = {"option1", "option2", "option3"};
        Object selectionObject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose", "Menu", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        String selectionString = selectionObject.toString();
        return selectionString;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me, please? Thank you in advance

Comment: Pass your main window as the first parameter instead of passing `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show JOptionPane on the top of all windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880981/how-to-show-joptionpane-on-the-top-of-all-windows)

Comment: Okay, I did it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Berger's suggestion, I solved my problem in the following way...

```
class Menu {
    public String showMenu(){
        //i solved my problem adding the following 2 lines of code...
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        Object[] options = {"option1", "option2", "option3"};
        //...and passing `frame` instead of `null` as first parameter
        Object selectionObject = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Choose", "Menu", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        String selectionString = selectionObject.toString();
        return selectionString;
    }
}
```